# how to reflect scala trait class field, use getDeclaredFields but got nothing?

Tags: scala, reflection, traits

```
var cl: URLClassLoader = _
var out: TaskStreams = _
var clazz = cl.loadClass("io.marsdigtal.XXX.UserTrait")

if (clazz.isInterface) {
  clazz = cl.loadClass(className + "$class")
  clazz.getDeclaredFields.foreach { each =>
  out.log.info("fieldName: " + each.getName)
  }
}
```

so I use getDeclaredFields, but got nothing...
how can I reflect trait fiedld by scala or java reflection?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't solve your problem specifically but if someone wants to get a list of fields on a known trait:

```
new SomeTrait{...}.getClass.getDeclaredFields
```

I was using this to [list fields in a trait hierarchy in dependency / declared order](https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/freshcode_public/learn_scala/syntax/src/main/scala/pckg_2_10/ReflectGetFieldsEtc.scala).

[EDIT] There is a caveat.  The fields can't be used for 'get'.  Obtain the real field on the class instance in question before calling 'get':

```
val real = cls.getDeclaredField(f.getName)
real.setAccessible(true)
real.get(someInst)
```